# Order a list but still be able to access index and fields

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to group a list of objects by a certain field.

Later on, I need to use this list as follows:

```
for(i=0; i< list.Count; i++)
{
   if(i == 0)
    continue;

   if (list[i].property != list[i-1].property)
   dosomething;
}
```

I need to do a for loop so I can say "if the property of the item right before this one was different...

The problem comes when I try to order the list. If I do list.GroupBy, I am unable to access the list items' members. If I do list.OrderBy, I have to set it to a ienumerable, and thereby can't use a for loop because ienumerables don't work with list indexes.

Is there a way to implement this functionality in a foreach loop (without referencing the index)? If not, is there another way to order my list that doesn't require it to be set to an ienumerable?

Comment: rather than `if(i==0)continue;` why not just initialize `i` to `1`?

Answer (score 3):

Four options:

- Use `OrderBy` and then `ToList` to get a sorted list. You can then use your existing code, although I'd recommend starting the loop at 1 rather than starting at 0 and breaking immediately in the first iteration.
- Use `OrderBy` and then `Zip`:

  ```
  var ordered = input.OrderBy(...);
  var zipped = ordered.Zip(ordered.Skip(1),
                           (Previous, Current) => new { Previous, Current });

  foreach (var pair in zipped)
  {
      if (pair.Previous.Property == pair.Current.Property)
      {
          ... Whatever you want to do
      }
  }
  ```

  Note that this will sort the input twice, unfortunately. There's no built-in way of avoiding that (without calling `ToList` or whatever). It wouldn't be too hard to write a "self-zip" extension method, admittedly.
- Use `OrderBy` and keep a "previous property":

  ```
  var ordered = input.OrderBy(...);
  // This is like using foreach, but with a simple way to get the
  // first item
  using (var iterator = ordered.GetEnumerator())
  {
      if (!iterator.MoveNext())
      {
          return; // Or whatever. No items!
      }
      var previousProperty = iterator.Current.Property;
      while (iterator.MoveNext())
      {
          var currentProperty = iterator.Current.Property;
          if (previousProperty == currentProperty)
          {
              ... Whatever you want to do
          }
          previousProperty = currentProperty;
      }
  }
  ```
- Sort the list in-place (if that doesn't mess anything else up) using `List<T>.Sort`

Comment: Your `zip` code would do the sorting twice.  That's a lot more work than just ordering it and re-populating a new list.  (You could then use zip rather than his code once you have a list/array.)

Comment: @Servy: Yes, I was editing to say that. I don't think it's worth using Zip when you've already got an array.

Comment: I suppose if you wanted to do it a lot you would just add a new overload to `Select` which provided by the current item, and previous, as parameters to the selector.  I think I might need to write that one for my own use...

Comment: @Servy: Why would you add it as an overload to `Select` rather than giving it a different name for clarity?

Comment: Because that's essentially what it would be doing, much like the overloads of `Select` that provide the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `myitem previous` just before the loop (where `myitem` is of the same type in your list) and then at the end of each list, set `previous` to the current item. If you do this, make sure to check `previous` for null since it won't have a value the first time around.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a repeat of one of the options from Skeet.  Give him the check.

ForEach does not require an index.  Cannot delete an item from the list with ForEach.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<SortMe> SortMes = new List<SortMe>();

        SortMes.Add(new SortMe("aaa"));
        SortMes.Add(new SortMe("bbb"));
        SortMes.Add(new SortMe("ccc"));
        SortMes.Add(new SortMe("aaa"));
        SortMes.Add(new SortMe("bbb"));
        SortMes.Add(new SortMe("ccc"));
        SortMes.Add(new SortMe("ccc"));
        SortMes.Add(new SortMe("bbb"));
        SortMes.Add(new SortMe("aaa"));
        SortMes.Add(new SortMe("ccc"));
        SortMes.Add(new SortMe("bbb"));
        SortMes.Add(new SortMe("aaa"));

        SortMe SortMeLast = null;

        foreach (SortMe SortMeCurrent in SortMes.OrderBy(x => x.Name))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   Current     " + SortMeCurrent.Name);
            if (SortMeLast != null)
            {
                if (SortMeCurrent.Name != SortMeLast.Name)
                {
                    // do something
                    Console.WriteLine("Do Something");
                }
            }
            SortMeLast = SortMeCurrent;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class SortMe
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SortMe(string name) { Name = name; } 
}
```